# PHP Multidimensional Array with SQL-Table-like structure and sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array wherein the first index contains the price of the items. On the second index, the name of the items are contained and the supplier details are stored in the third. I would like to sort the array via the prices in ascending order. Once I do the sorting, I need to ensure that the item names and suppliers are still in line with the price.

Example:

```
$data = array();
$data["price"][0] = 20;
$data["price"][1] = 25;
$data["price"][2] - 15;

$data["name"][0] = "Apple";
$data["name"][1] = "Orange";
$data["name"][2] = "Peach";

$data["supplier"][0] = "Supplier 1";
$data["supplier"][1] = "Supplier 5";
$data["supplier"][2] = "Supplier 2";

/* sorting code here */

Expected result:
15 - Peach - Supplier 2
20 - Apple - Supplier 1
25 - Orange - Supplier 5
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you tried something?? because `usort()` will help you or `array_multisort()` will help you

Comment: _“Once I do the sorting, I need to ensure that the item names and suppliers are still in line with the price.”_ - yes, with such a sub-optimal data structure, you would have to take extra steps to ensure that. This should be the other way around - `$data[0]['price']`, `$data[0]['name']`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revamped into new array structure and then foreach,

```
$result=[];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
        $result[$i][$key] = $value[$i]; // $i(int) as key and $key as subkey
    }
}
// sorting by price
array_multisort(array_column($result, 'price'), SORT_ASC, $result);
foreach ($result as $value) {
    echo implode(" - ", $value)."\n";
}
```

[array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LKZ99)

Output:-

```
15 - Peach - Supplier 2
20 - Apple - Supplier 1
25 - Orange - Supplier 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It worked like magic. I will study the demo you provided.